# Rotate only one view in tab bar

Tags: ios7, rotation, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar with four items. i need to rotate only one item, but i don't understand how to do.I tried this, but doesn't work.

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
 return NO; 
}`

I'm working in ios 7 and storyboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that. Whatever the *allowed* rotation settings are for the tab bar controller (through its delegate method `tabBarControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:`), those are the *allowed* rotation settings for *all* of its items. The only way to *force* rotation in iOS 7 is to put up a presented (modal) view with `presentViewController:` (modal segue).

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand. Can you do an example, please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this example

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/download/file.php?id=1464&sid=42c0876f615fa632a49be7b89d203f6e